# Pascal's Triangle Loop Produce Unnecessary NaN

Tags: r, for-loop

What's wrong?

```
pascals_triangle <- function(x) {
  for (i in 1:x) {
    holder <- c()
    n <- i - 1
    for (j in 1:x) {
      r <- j - 1
      nCrlessone <- factorial(n)/(factorial(n-r)*factorial(r))
      holder <- c(holder, nCrlessone)
    }
  print(holder)
  }
}



> pascals_triangle(1)
 [1] 1
> pascals_triangle(10)
 [1]   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [1]   1   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [1]   1   2   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [1]   1   3   3   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [1]   1   4   6   4   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [1]   1   5  10  10   5   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [1]   1   6  15  20  15   6   1 NaN NaN NaN
 [1]   1   7  21  35  35  21   7   1 NaN NaN
 [1]   1   8  28  56  70  56  28   8   1 NaN
 [1]   1   9  36  84 126 126  84  36   9   1
```

See the result above not printing NaN on the first trial.
See the result above not printing NaN on the first trial.
See the result above not printing NaN on the first trial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid computing, storing, and then displaying the `NaN` values, then you may change the bounds of the loop in `j` to go from `1:i` rather than `1:x`:

```
pascals_triangle <- function(x) {
    for (i in 1:x) {
        holder <- c()
        n <- i - 1
        for (j in 1:i) {
            r <- j - 1
            nCrlessone <- factorial(n)/(factorial(n-r)*factorial(r))
            holder <- c(holder, nCrlessone)
        }
        print(holder)
    }
}

pascals_triangle(10)

[1] 1
[1] 1  1
[1] 1  2  1
[1] 1  3  3  1
[1] 1  4  6  4   1
[1] 1  5 10 10   5   1
[1] 1  6 15 20  15   6   1
[1] 1  7 21 35  35  21   7  1
[1] 1  8 28 56  70  56  28  8 1
[1] 1  9 36 84 126 126  84 36 9  1
```

This change ensures that you only compute the lower sub diagonal.

Comment: Thanks, Tim! May you enlighten me what happened there?

Comment: You were looping twice over the same bounds, which resulted in over computing of the upper diagonal.

Comment: Tim, do you have a better solution? Please do surprise me.